# TemplateSyntaxError: widget_tweaks is not a valid library django

Tags: python, django, django-widget-tweaks

I am new to django and I am trying to trying to implement a form that uses widget-tweaks.

I did install widget tweaks (I am using Ubuntu 14.04)

```
sudo pip install django-widget-tweaks
```

My settings file looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'core',
'addattr',
'widget_tweaks',
)
```

The html looks like this:

```
{% extends "base/theme.html" %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block main_content %}
...more code...
```

The class in the views and the linking in the url works perfectly fine.

But every time when I try to load the html it says:

```
widget_tweaks' is not a valid tag library: Template library widget_tweaks not found, tried django.templatetags.widget_tweaks,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.widget_tweaks,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.widget_tweaks
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like `widget_tweaks` isn't on the PYTHONPATH. If you're not already, my recommendation would be to use virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper to install modules via pip. https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **ubuntu use pip3**

#### step 1:

convert

```
sudo pip install django-widget-tweaks
```

to:

```
sudo pip3 install django-widget-tweaks
```

#### step 2:

add name lib in settings.py

you can use :

```
INSTALLED_APPS+=['widget-tweaks']
```

or
inside

INSTALLED_APPS

#### step 3:

in templates use:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
```

test:

in templates

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<!-- change input type (e.g. to HTML5) -->
{% render_field form.search_query type="search" %}
```

Comment: I get **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widget-tweaks'**. I have installed django-widget-tweaks

Comment: So I had to add it under the apps. I guess that's why the pypi documentations says to add it like this `INSTALLED_APPS += [
    'widget_tweaks',
]` https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/

Answer (score 6):

check your app settings add :

```
'widget_tweaks',
```

to your INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 1):

you installed the `widget_tweaks` as super admin and maybe you were using a virtualenv just do `pip install django-widget-tweaks`

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**:

```
pip install django-widget-tweaks
```

**Step 2**:

In settings.py, add `'widget_tweaks'`, under `INSTALLED_APPS`

This problem will be resolved.